# parallel: Error: Command line too long (68914 >= 65524) at input 0

Tags: gnu-parallel

Given a file with long lines, `parallel` fails to pass these lines as an argument to any command:

```
$> cat johny_long_lines.txt | parallel echo {}
parallel: Error: Command line too long (68906 >= 65524) at input 0: 2236439425|\x308286873082856fa003020102020c221ff03...
```

This gets more confusing when I see that the line is `68900` characters long:

```
$> cat johny_long_lines.txt | head -n 1 | wc -m
68900
```

***while*** the max line length allowed by parallel is way more longer that my input:

```
$> parallel --max-line-length-allowed
131049
```

Also: if you think that it's a problem of `execve`, this might interest you:

```
$> getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
```

Any idea what I'm doing here wrong?

### UPDATE

I figured out that the problem persists for versions `20161222` and `20220522` but not for `20210822` (delivered with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS). Further inspection reveals that this line causes the problem:

```perl
# Usable len = maxlen - 3000 for wrapping, div 2 for hexing
int(($Global::minimal_command_line_length - 3000)/2);
```

Which I can confirm using `--show-limits`:

```
$> parallel --show-limits
[...]

Maximal size of command: 131063
Maximal usable size of command: 64031
```

This annoying *feature* does not exist in version `20210822` and I my file goes through as expected.

Can this be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I got the message

```
parallel --show-limits
Maximal size of command: 131049
Maximal used size of command: 83906
```

and had some trouble finding the source for the 83906
but then found it in

```
~/.parallel/tmp/sshlogin/$(hostname)/linelen
```

and had no clue how it was set to this small value.
But the Version of parallel was quite old:

```
GNU parallel 20180922
```